# How to add favicon.ico to site using document root

Tags: php

I tried to add icon with code
    `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/imageslogos     /favicon.ico'); ?>" />`
When I look at the source code it showed lots of ? a few letters and numbers
When I clicked on this it said
The requested URL's length exceeds the capacity
limit for this server.
How do I add the icon from document root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use the include function since the link tag needs a reference.
Try this

```
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="
    <?php echo $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/imageslogos/favicon.ico"; ?>
  "/>
```